# Unit test for uses-permission permissions

Tags: android, android-testing, android-permissions

I'm trying to figure a way to test if `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is set in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but I can't. Is it possible to do that? Right now I'm using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`.

I'm trying to learn testing in Android Studio, and I think that testing that certain uses-permission permissions are set is a good idea at the start of testing the application.

Comment: Try `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageManager()` to get a `PackageManager`. From there, you should be able find the app and see what permissions it requests.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
Context testContext = getActivity().getContext();
PackageManager pm = testContext.getPackageManager();

expected = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
actual = pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.<PERMISSION_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR>, testContext.getPackageName());
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```